# display link after finishing coutdown time

Tags: javascript

I am using [Jquery Countdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown) module. In this, user can display text message after completing countdown. But I want to display a link after completing countdown.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the project page. It says

You can use jQuery Countdown in two different ways, one is using `theme('jquery_countdown')`, the other is using `jquery_countdown_add()`.

In the following example, we display an alert box saying "You are done!" after counting down from 10...

```
<?php
  echo '<div class="countdown">10 seconds!</div>';
  jquery_countdown_add(".countdown", array("until" => 10, "onExpiry" => "finished"));
  drupal_add_js("function finished() { alert('You are done!'); }", 'inline');
?>
```

You can use the above example to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Can you explain?where can i write this code?

Comment: Have a look at Readme.txt file under the module folder and follow the instructions. BTW you didn't provide any details to us like where you are using the countdown timer.